# actual training samples and samples visible in epochs while running are different

Tags: python, keras

I have **191033** samples out of which 90% are used for training and the remaining 10% for testing which is **171929** and **19104** for training and testing respectively.
when I fit the model using model.fit() and execute, it shows only **2457** samples instead of **171929**....here is the snapshot of the output..

```
y shape is (191033,)  and X shape is (191033, 77)  
y-train shape is (171929,)  and y-test shape is (19104,)  
x-train shape is (171929, 77)  and x-test shape is (19104, 77)  
Epoch 1/100  
**2457**/**2457** [=======] - 4s 2ms/step - loss: 0.0274 - accuracy: 0.9918 -  lr: 0.0010
```

and this is the code where fit function is used..

```
model.fit(X_train,y_train,batch_size = 70, epochs = 100,callbacks=[klrf])
```

any suggestions as to why this is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number displayed is the number of batches in the training set, `171929/70=2456.1`, so 2457 batches in total.